# divide by zero in specific case in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting Divide by zero error for the following statement.

```
select ((((57151130.0000000000)+(57612530.0000000000))/2)/((12548020.0000000000)-(34321580.0000000000)+(21773560.0000000000)))*366
```

Comment: (12548020.0000000000)-(34321580.0000000000)+(21773560.0000000000) = 0

Comment: How to handle this

Comment: What do you want as result in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that you are supplying literal values is a little odd, however, one method of avoiding a divide by 0 error is using [NULLIF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

`NULLIF` takes 2 parameters. If the values of the 2 expressions for the parameters are the same value, then `NULLIF` returns `NULL`, otherwise it returns the value of the first expression. For example (in literal terms):

```
SELECT NULLIF(1,0), NULLIF('a' + 'b' + 'c','abc');
```

This returns the values `1` and `NULL`. For your query, the format would therefore be:

```
SELECT (((57151130.0000000000+57612530.0000000000)/2)/NULLIF(12548020.0000000000-34321580.0000000000+21773560.0000000000,0))*366
```

*Note I have removed several of the parenthesis as there's no need to wrap every value/expression in a pair. Doing so will likely lower readability.*

Then, if the expression under the divisor has the value `0`, the value `NULL` will be returned instead. Considering that `NULL` represents an unknown value, and `{expr}/0` is certainly an unknown value as well, the value would be the most appropriate.

If you then need to represent the `NULL` value in a particular way, you can wrap the **whole** expression in a further `ISNULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can use `CASE` to check zero values statement:

```
select (
(((57151130.0000000000)+(57612530.0000000000))/2)
/    
CASE WHEN((12548020.0000000000)-(34321580.0000000000)+(21773560.0000000000)) = 0 THEN NULL
ELSE ((12548020.0000000000)-(34321580.0000000000)+(21773560.0000000000))
END
)*366
```